# Is there a git revert similar to svn revert? I need a single command to erase *everything* in my local and set it to remote head

Tags: git, github

In svn or subclipse, I can simply do a 'revert' on the root project and all my local changes are discarded and src is updated to the latest in HEAD. I don't seem to find an equivalent of this in git though several blogs claim the same.

This is what I did:

- committed 10 files from my home mac. did not push.
- committed the same 10 files and more from work computer and PUSHED.
- came back home and I want to take the latest from remote origin/master.

tried git pull, it brought in changes but warned of conflict

tried `git reset --hard HEAD`, but nothing happened. I still see the committed conflicted changes

I must've tried few other commands I don't remember. I just need to get back to remote head and not worry about what state my local repo is.

Help?

Comment: did you mean: git reset **--hard** HEAD

Comment: Please reformulate the question title. "svn revert" can revert individual files and directories. You asked for reverting *all* local changes and got a correct answer which is not helpful for people looking for an actual equivalent to "svn revert", yet Google finds your question when searching for, e.g., "svn revert git"

Comment: google search "svn revert git" is still showing this question first and only the start of the title : "Is there a git revert similar to svn revert"... the answer to that is `$ git checkout file1`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to reset to origin/master:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Answer (score 7):

`git reset --hard @{u}` will throw away all local changes and reset your current branch to its upstream branch. This only works if you've set that information (e.g. by cloning with a recent version of git, or by using `git push -u`). If you don't have that info but you know the upstream branch, you can use `git reset --hard origin/master` (assuming `origin/master` here is the name of the upstream branch).

Answer (score 1):

You want `git reset`, but you probably want to go back one commit earlier, since you committed those files to your HEAD on the home mac.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

If you're concerned about wrecking something up, you can always do `git log`, grab the hash for the commit you want to go back to (discarding your home mac changes), and `git reset --hard` to that hash.

Comment: Great. It worked but had some untracked files. I ran a git clean -f and that was removed. Now git status shows this:

# On branch master
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 1 and 18 different commit(s) each, respectively.

I thought my local is now same as remote ... ?

Answer (score 1):

For simple **revert** you can use: [git checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

```
git checkout <master>
```